I'm a government employee. Can I be fired without cause or without a RIF order?
I'm an engineer at a government research lab. There are three people in my group, including myself, for whom my manager brings in funding. He's told me it's getting increasingly difficult to find money, but he shuts me down when I've asked him about writing proposals for new projects or talking with other people in our branch about how we can support them. I'm a 64-year-old woman and my coworkers are guys in their 30s and 40s. He has not talked to them about how tight money is; only me. I'm not sure he's allowed to say that he wants me to retire but I suspect that's what he wants me to do. While managers can get rid of any employee if they have the motivation, they'd have to work hard to fire me since I have been a federal employee for 20 years and have a good performance record. If anyone has had a similar experience or thoughts to share, I'd love to read about them.

Please reconsider your need to use your real name/photo for a post like this.

Protections for government employees (or employees in general) are not the same everywhere in the world. Without a location, this is impossible to answer - and that's assuming there is a general answer to this that is not overridden by whatever's in your contract.

Without knowing which government, that is impossible to answer. I'm sure you are aware that there are grave differences between countries, an answer for France and an answer for North Korea will be totally different and you are mislead if you are in a third country and believe what you read applies to yours. Please state your country and state if applicable.

Yes; A Reduction in Force can happen at any point, normally after an work force assessment, most of the time requested by congress. Many factors will go into who losses their job due to a RIF. Seniority (time in service) keeps you safe. This is only applicable to federal service within the United States. Furthermore, the entire research lab can lose it's funding, that would be mean nobody keeps their job.  Your rights will vary based on what happens. For instance, you might be offered a job, if you turn that job down, you are on your own to find another one.

If you just google "RIF order" (a.k.a Reduction in Force"), it says it's for the US Federal government, and that specific term doesn't seem to apply to any other government.

Firing someone because of their age is illegal in the US no matter who you work for.

I wish I could write an answer here. My serious advice would be to give serious thought to retiring. Work out how much money you would need to make retirement work for you financially, given your presumably substantial pension. If you really miss the work itself, see if you could do a deal to come back as a part time contractor. If you negotiate now you might get a good deal. If you stay and fight you might come to hate your job over the next few years.


Can I be fired without cause or without a RIF order?

That depends very much with country/state you are working in, what local labor laws are in place, what government rules you are subject too, what specifically your contract says, and what other rules your union or equivalent (if any) have been negotiated.
I've certainly seen clauses in government research employment contracts that amounts to "no funding, no job". However, the enforceability of these varies a lot by location and other local laws. If you need a legal reading, talk to your union rep (if you gave something like this) or a local labor lawyer. Government rules tend to be convoluted.
It's possible that your boss wants you out. In this case you have a few options

Ignore it. If he wants to get rid of you he needs to fire you. Make sure you understand what rights you have and what benefits you are entitled to (severance, insurance coverage, notice period, etc). Again this is highly variable and specific to your situation and contract
Offer him a deal: Figure out what severance you are entitled to and multiply it by 2 or 3. Firing someone is a lot of work. In your case could also be legally risky since it basically screams age discrimination (which may or may not be legal in your country). Now you want to be subtle about it: Don't approach this as "If you pay me enough, I leave". A better way is "I was wondering if we could find a mutual beneficial solution for the funding problem you keep bringing up".
Just retire. That's the least amount of effort and stress.


I agree with this answer for the most part, but trying to get 2x or 3x severance, if the author is a federal employee and NOT a contractor is not realistic.  Of course, we don't know what they are because, they didn't tell us.
